# SQL Server : how to set a column to a random value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, migration

I'm using SQL Server, I'm not experienced in T-SQL, but I want to generate random value including letters and numbers for one column for my project:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders] 
(
    [Id]               INT NOT NULL,
    [UserId]           INT NOT NULL,
    [MedicineId]       INT NOT NULL,
    [CourierId]        INT NULL,
    [ReadyForDelivery] BIT NOT NULL,
    [OrderNumber]      NVARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Orders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

`Id` is my primary key also I want to put a random number and letters in the `OrderNumber` column. How can I do that?

I use migration when I'm creating this table

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Orders",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    UserId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    MedicineId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    CourierId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    ReadyForDelivery = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                    OrderNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Orders", x => x.Id);
                });
}
```

Comment: Pre-generate a big set of random values, then just take them off the stack. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3055/generating-random-numbers-in-sql-server-without-collisions/

Comment: SQL Server also supports sequences: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver16